# Opera error : Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'xxxxxx' to object

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, opera, uncaught-exception

i come today to show an error thrown by opera in Jquery ,about object transformation , here is the code ( function setColor(x,y) ):

```
colourpixel = $('#colour').css('background-color').match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);//["rgb(0, 70, 255", "0", "70", "255"]

var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.height=190;
canvas.width=190;
canvascontext = canvas.getContext("2d");
defaultdata = $('#light').get(0).getContext("2d").getImageData(0,0,190,190);
canvascontext.putImageData(defaultdata,0,0);

canvascontext.globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-atop';
canvascontext.fillStyle='rgb( '+colourpixel[1]+', '+colourpixel[2]+', '+colourpixel[3]+')';
```

And here is the error thrown by opera :

```
Uncaught exception: TypeError: Cannot convert 'colourpixel' to object  
Error thrown at line 157, column 1 in setColor(x, y) in   file://localhost/home/angelus/Desarrollo/webs/ColorP/functions.js:  
    canvascontext.fillStyle='rgb( '+colourpixel[1]+', '+colourpixel[2]+',   '+colourpixel[3]+')';
called from line 61, column 2 in <anonymous function>(event) in file://localhost/home/angelus/Desarrollo/webs/ColorP/functions.js:
    setColor(x,y);
called from line 55, column 294 in <anonymous function: handle>(a) in file://localhost/home/angelus/Desarrollo/webs/ColorP/jquery.min.js:
    i=i.handler.apply(this,arguments);
called via Function.prototype.apply() from line 49, column 569 in <anonymous function: o>() in file://localhost/home/angelus/Desarrollo/webs/ColorP/jquery.min.js:
    return typeof c!=="undefined"&&!c.event.triggered?c.event.handle.apply(o.elem,arguments):w
```

I have tried to create the object like an array ( var colourpixel = new Array(); ) but nothing run.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Nick "the error thrown by opera"

Comment: @Angelus Why not add the final bracket to the regex and do `canvascontext.fillStyle = colourpixel[0];`?

Comment: Cause if i put a ; there , there is a sintax problem width the String conection no?

Comment: @lonesomeday - wow missed that without the capital, yeah Opera is going to convert it to a `#XXXXXX` hex format, it doesn't return the original `rgb(...)` format, so you're getting a `null` for the match back here.

Comment: @Angelus - In "Opera", the problem is in Opera, when you do say `background-color: rgb(0, 70, 255);` what you'll get from `.css('background-color')` is `#0046ff`, not the original format...so no match on your regex and `colourpixel` is `null`.

Comment: oh yes i have seen now , thx for the answer , write it like answer and ill put you the answer like correct , thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure the best fix since I don't deal with this color situation at all, but here's that the problem is:

In opera when you set a style as `rgb(...)`, for example:

```
<div id="colour" style="background-color: rgb(0, 70, 255);">​
```

In most browser's for `$('#colour').css('background-color')` you'll get: `"rgb(0, 70, 255)"`, but that's not true in Opera, you'll get a hex format of `"#0046ff"`, so your regex won't match and `colourpixel` will be `null`, not an array of matches.  This causes your errors, the same as `null[1]` would.

[Here's a quick test to demonstrate this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JFGbf/), test it in any other major browser, then Opera.